# ERROR: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8" inserting in pgadmin

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I am having issues while inserting data in postgres which has a character é . 
While inserting this character through PGADMIN, it parses the character to ETX, while the pgsql shell parses it to ^C. When I keep the query with character in a file and pass the file in psql shel it gives me an error :

ERROR: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x82

My Postgres 9.0 Db encoding is set to UTF-8.

Please let me know how to deal with these kind of characters.

Thanks,
Rohit.

PS: I am not sure if the character can be seen here properly. It is a box drawing character which is represented in
ASCII as – 192 and
UTF- 8 as - U+2514

---

Comment: 0x82 means that your client (pgadmin) uses code page 437,850 or 858. Somewhere you should specify this encoding. Postgres is set to utf8 (which is fine) but somewhere between the client and the backend your 0x82 (which is an invalid byte in utf8) should be converted.

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution is to find out what encoding your client is using `SET client_encoding`

For example this may fix your problem:

```
SET client_encoding = 'WIN1252';
```

If you are on Windows with pgadmin, a client encoding of Windows 1252 would be the most likely cause of the problem.